# Apple rejection based on method names

Tags: api, chat, sdk, private

Apple has just rejected our app based on what they call "non-public API usage." In their email they identify a number of method names which they consider possible violations of their non-public API policy. Among these are:

- initWithLabel:
- setRequired:

Based on our analysis, these names are coming not from our code, but from the Salesforce SDKBits SDK that we have integrated to provide in-app Chat functionality.
Apple does not say that these names are necessarily private API usage, but they do say that we need to change them anyway. Here's the quote:
"If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions."
Is there any way we can get a build of the SDK which removes the 2 names listed above?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! While there are some Salesforce employees floating around here, the vast majority of us are simply knowledgeable users who volunteer our time to help others out. There may be other iOS developers that would be willing to share their tricks, but I wouldn't count on getting something like a custom SDK build.

Comment: Only posted here because the SF support team made me do it.